# How to print all the values out in my Neural Network output?

Tags: python, neural-network, conv-neural-network

**I would like to print out all the output values but it seems that my code only display the beginning and the ending of my output values **

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random as r
:
:
:

v=learn(X_train, weights,1)
print(v)

Listed below are the outputs 

[[0.12345678 0.01203133 0.96186337 ... 0.96412521 0.97920999 0.96611316]
 [0.82937129 0.01231312 0.95248526 ... 0.95767466 0.97077245 0.95934315]
 [0.02193183 0.02193183 0.9467715  ... 0.94860868 0.96656235 0.95388446]
 ...
 [0.95179248 0.96927033 0.95972817 ... 0.95540086 0.97634404 0.96075726]
 [0.92174479 0.95436756 0.9368558  ... 0.92103805 0.96243975 0.92116693]
 [0.94013468 0.95103059 0.95334856 ... 0.95566716 0.97187315 0.95775099]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Long outputs might get truncated by some IDE's.
You can prevent that by printing each row one by one.
(Warning, this might take some time).

```
for row in v:
    for value in row:
       print(row, end=' ')
    print()
```